# JQ replacing values in one array based on values from different array

Tags: arrays, jq, substitution

I would like in JQ to substitute the values in the first array with the names in the second array based on the key "size" while keeping the length of the first array unchanged.

```
[
    [{\"size\":0},{\"size\":1},{\"size\":2},{\"size\":3},{\"size\":4},{\"size\":5},{\"size\":6},{\"size\":7},{\"size\":8},{\"size\":9},{\"size\":0},{\"size\":1},{\"size\":2},{\"size\":3},{\"size\":4},{\"size\":5},{\"size\":6},{\"size\":7},{\"size\":8},{\"size\":0},{\"size\":1},{\"size\":2},{\"size\":3},{\"size\":4},{\"size\":5},{\"size\":6},{\"size\":7},{\"size\":8}]
    
    [{\"size\":0,\"name\":\"6M\"},{\"size\":1,\"name\":\"6.5M\"},{\"size\":2,\"name\":\"7M\"},{\"size\":3,\"name\":\"7.5M\"},{\"size\":4,\"name\":\"8M\"},{\"size\":5,\"name\":\"8.5M\"},{\"size\":6,\"name\":\"9M\"},{\"size\":7,\"name\":\"9.5M\"},{\"size\":8,\"name\":\"10M\"},{\"size\":9,\"name\":\"11M\"}]

]
```

So the wanted result would look like this:

```
[{\"size\":6M},{\"size\":6.5M},{\"size\":7M},{\"size\":7.5M},{\"size\":8M},{\"size\":8.5M},{\"size\":9M},{\"size\":9.5M},{\"size\":10M},{\"size\":11M},{\"size\":6M},{\"size\":6.5M},{\"size\":7M},{\"size\":7.5M},{\"size\":8M},{\"size\":8.5M},{\"size\":9M},{\"size\":9.5M},{\"size\":10M},{\"size\":6M},{\"size\":6.5M},{\"size\":7M},{\"size\":7.5M},{\"size\":8M},{\"size\":8.5M},{\"size\":9M},{\"size\":9.5M},{\"size\":10M}]
```

I used this input to obtain the above arrays `jq " [ .DATA.product.traits|([.colors.colorMap[]| {size:.sizes[]}]), ( [ .sizes.sizeMap[]| {size:.id, name}])]"` and then tried using if-then-else statement (`|if (.[0:-1][][].size == .[-1][].size) then [.[-1][].name ] else null end"`) but I was unable to reach the desired output..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With **json** input file:

```
[
    [
        {"size":0},{"size":1},{"size":2},{"size":3},{"size":4},
        {"size":5},{"size":6},{"size":7},{"size":8},{"size":9},
        {"size":0},{"size":1},{"size":2},{"size":3},{"size":4},
        {"size":5},{"size":6},{"size":7},{"size":8},{"size":0},
        {"size":1},{"size":2},{"size":3},{"size":4},{"size":5},
        {"size":6},{"size":7},{"size":8}
    ],
    [
        {"size":0,"name":"6M"},{"size":1,"name":"6.5M"},
        {"size":2,"name":"7M"},{"size":3,"name":"7.5M"},
        {"size":4,"name":"8M"},{"size":5,"name":"8.5M"},
        {"size":6,"name":"9M"},{"size":7,"name":"9.5M"},
        {"size":8,"name":"10M"},{"size":9,"name":"11M"}
    ]
]
```

and jq **filter** file:

```
. as $in |
reduce $in[1][] as $i ({}; .[$i.size|tostring] = $i.name) | . as $d |
reduce $in[0][] as $j ([]; . += [{ "size" : $d[$j.size|tostring] }])
```

you can run:

```
jq -c -f filter json
```

giving (wrapped for legibility):

```
[{"size":"6M"},{"size":"6.5M"},{"size":"7M"},{"size":"7.5M"},
{"size":"8M"},{"size":"8.5M"},{"size":"9M"},{"size":"9.5M"},
{"size":"10M"},{"size":"11M"},{"size":"6M"},{"size":"6.5M"},
{"size":"7M"},{"size":"7.5M"},{"size":"8M"},{"size":"8.5M"},
{"size":"9M"},{"size":"9.5M"},{"size":"10M"},{"size":"6M"},
{"size":"6.5M"},{"size":"7M"},{"size":"7.5M"},{"size":"8M"},
{"size":"8.5M"},{"size":"9M"},{"size":"9.5M"},{"size":"10M"}]
```

---

Alternative **filter**:

```
. as $in |
reduce $in[1][] as $i ({}; .[$i.size|tostring] = $i.name) | . as $d |
$in[0] | map_values ( .size = $d[.size|tostring] )
```

Comment: @peak are you able to tell me why this is marked as a duplicate when the other question was asked later and the only answer does not actually produce the requested output?

Answer (score 0):

I first grouped by array2 into an object for easier lookup when iterating the first array.

```js
var str1 = "[{\"size\":0},{\"size\":1},{\"size\":2},{\"size\":3},{\"size\":4},{\"size\":5},{\"size\":6},{\"size\":7},{\"size\":8},{\"size\":9},{\"size\":0},{\"size\":1},{\"size\":2},{\"size\":3},{\"size\":4},{\"size\":5},{\"size\":6},{\"size\":7},{\"size\":8},{\"size\":0},{\"size\":1},{\"size\":2},{\"size\":3},{\"size\":4},{\"size\":5},{\"size\":6},{\"size\":7},{\"size\":8}]"

var str2 = "[{\"size\":0,\"name\":\"6M\"},{\"size\":1,\"name\":\"6.5M\"},{\"size\":2,\"name\":\"7M\"},{\"size\":3,\"name\":\"7.5M\"},{\"size\":4,\"name\":\"8M\"},{\"size\":5,\"name\":\"8.5M\"},{\"size\":6,\"name\":\"9M\"},{\"size\":7,\"name\":\"9.5M\"},{\"size\":8,\"name\":\"10M\"},{\"size\":9,\"name\":\"11M\"}]"

var arr1 = JSON.parse(str1)
var arr2 = JSON.parse(str2)


var obj2 = arr2.reduce(function(agg, item) {
  agg[item.size] = item
  return agg;
}, {})


arr1.map(function(item) {
  item.size = obj2["" + item.size].name;
})

console.log(arr1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: The OP asked for a jq answer.

Comment: @peak the question was only edited to mention jq after this answer was written

Comment: Thanks. Also vanilla javascript works with jquery.